# Iterate through Facebook GraphObject

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, facebook-php-sdk, associative-array

I need to figure out how to iterate through a Facebook group feed that's returned as an object from the Facebook graph. Everything is working fine until I try to go through the object and get all the data so that I can format and print it.

This is my request...

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/group_id/feed' );
$response = $request->execute();
$object = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

It returns the feed of my group in an object, for example...

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => POST ID
                [from] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => MEMBER ID
                        [name] => MEMBER NAME
                    )

                [to] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => Film Club
                                        [id] => GROUP ID
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [message] => MESSAGE
                [picture] => PICTURE URL
                [link] => LINK URL
                [icon] => https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif
                [actions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => Comment
                                [link] => LINK
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => Like
                                [link] => LINK
                            )

                    )

                [privacy] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [value] => 
                    )

                [type] => photo
                [object_id] => OBJECT ID
                [application] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => Facebook for iPhone
                        [namespace] => fbiphone
                        [id] => ID
                    )

                [created_time] => 2014-10-02T00:39:00+0000
                [updated_time] => 2014-10-02T00:51:53+0000
                [likes] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => ID
                                        [name] => NAME
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => ID
                                        [name] => NAME
                                    )

                            )

                        [paging] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [cursors] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [after] => ODI5MTk3ODI3MTEzOTk1
                                        [before] => MTU1NjEwNzcxMTI3MjIyNQ==
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [comments] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => COMMENT ID
                                        [from] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => MEMBER ID
                                                [name] => NAME
                                            )

                                        [message] => COMMENT
                                        [can_remove] => 1
                                        [created_time] => 2014-10-02T00:45:23+0000
                                        [like_count] => 1
                                        [user_likes] => 
                                    )
                            )

                        [paging] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [cursors] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [after] => WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNamczT0RreU9EQXhOREF4TlRnd09qRTBNVEl5TVRFeE1UTTZMVEU9
                                        [before] => WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNamczT0RreE5EazBOek0xTURRME9qRTBNVEl5TVRBM01qTTZMVEU9
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

And to loop through all this I've tried a number of different things, stuff I've found here and everywhere else on the internet. I haven't been able to find any way to output more than just the POST ID. It's been a while since I've programmed anything, but this shouldn't be this hard. Can anyone help me figure this out?